# Express node.js - understanding routing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this `about.js` route and it works fine but I don't understand how `/` in `router.get()` would work while `/about` wouldn't?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('about', { title: 'About' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

----------------- **UPDATE** ----------------------

It's basically what I got out of the box after installing express.js
except the about lines.

I expected `router.get('/about' ...)` in `about.js` would work but it threw an error and it worked with `/` instead and that's what bugs me.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var about = require('./routes/about');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/about', about);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Could you explain a little better, please?

Comment: need more explaination

Comment: I've edited my question slightly. Basically I understand how `/` works for index.js but not for other routes.

Comment: What do you mean by `/about` not working? If you want the function to run when you visit `http://yourpage.tld/about`, you of course need a route for that: `router.get('/about', function(req, res, next){ /* your code */});`.

Comment: That's what I thought but I get error when I do that. Instead `/` would work when visiting `http://example.com/about`

Comment: @SeongLee Well then it would be a good idea to write about it too. Write what you've tried, what errors you got, etc. The problem description is very vague and it's not absolutely clear what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem

When you define a route on your app.js as you did with `app.use('/about', about);`. You are already telling express that you expect requests to hit http://yourserver/about route.

If you try to define `/about` again inside your **about.js** with:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('about', { title: 'About' });
});
```

What you're doing is tellig the Express that you will hit a /about inside your firstly declared /about. So it will expect requests on this route: http://yourserver/about/about

> The solution

It's actually what you're using. Define a root route inside your **about.js** as:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('about', { title: 'About' });
});
```

This way your app will be:

- Modular since you're using different files for different routes (about.js, users.js)
- Easier to read
- With simplier routes inside each file, since you don't need to type `/about` everytime you wish to create a new route.

If you wish a http://yourserver/about/help simply add a handler inside your route file **about.js** as here:

```
router.get('/help', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('help', { title: 'Help' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the route `/about` work then you have to create another route:

```
router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('about-page', { title: 'About' });
});
```

because `/` will only work for the home page.